# How can I get dynamically a number out of a bigger number?

Tags: php, numbers, str-replace

I have a number e.g. `115040030`.

The pattern of the number is (Pseudo pattern): `1[year][month]XXXX`

So here a few examples with input / expected output:

```
115040030  ->   30
115040130  ->  130
115041130  -> 1130
```

I tried with `str_replace()`, but this isn't dynamic:

```
$var = "115040030";
echo str_replace('1150400', $var);
```

So how can I dynamically grab the expected output from the number?

Comment: What is the pattern behind this?

Comment: Is `11504` same for all?

Comment: `$number = 115041130; echo $number - 115040000;` Looks like straightforward mathematics to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Since you just want the last 4 characters use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and then simply cast it to an int)

```
echo (int) substr($str, -4);
```

input/output:

```
115040030   ->   30
115040130   ->  130
115041130   -> 1130
```

Comment: thanks working like a charm :) when ever i struggle with the answer u are helping me thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$pattern = 1.date('ym');
echo str_replace($pattern, '', $var);
```